# How to hash a string to a number

Tags: c++, c, hash

I am trying to simulate dynamic hashing for my database class. Here they have said to use a hashing function to generate a 32 bit binary string from a regular string. How to I do that? I have never done that before and I have searched the internet but I am not understanding anything. Here is an example - 
input - "Computer Science"
output - "1101 0101 0100 0111 1101 0101 0100 0111"

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer in the dupe seems appropriate.

Comment: See the following blog article for a couple of hash functions, one from the original K&R, the other from one Bob Jenkins with fairly decent distribution: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=615